# How to create a dataframe only if all columns contains a certain value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let's say I have a dataframe that looks like the following

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Mark 123 |
| 456 | Mark 456 |
| 789 | 789 |

How do I create a df on spark scala with the following conditions: If all column B values contain a "mark", a dataframe with column A is created, else, an empty dataframe is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simply make a count with `contains "mark"` in order to evaluate if all rows have it. I think this should do the trick:

```
import spark.implicits._

val dfWithMark = Seq(
("123", "Mark 123"),
("456", "Mark 456"),
("789", "Mark 789")
).toDF("column A", "column B")

def buildMarkDf(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val count = df.count()
  val markCount = df.where(lower($"column B") contains "mark").count()

  if (count == markCount)
    df.select("column a")
  else
    spark.emptyDataFrame
}

buildMarkDf(dfWithMark).show(false)
```

With this statement `df.where(lower($"column B") contains "mark").count()` if all columns contain Mark, the count should be the same as the `originalDataframe.count()`